# iOS 11: Facebook Login not working

Tags: swift, facebook, ios11

I want to use custom URL schemes as well as Facebook Login, but it's not working:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool
```

but Facebook expects a return value of

```
FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(_:application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation:annotation)
```

so I can't fill out the necessary parameters when using the new `openUrl` method. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `FBSDKApplicationDelegate.application(_: open: options:)` instead.

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    if FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options) {
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
    } else {
        //fallback if FBSDKApplicationDelegate cannot open URL
    }
}
```

Comment: but this method is not called when my app is opened via custom url scheme

Comment: @swalkner Upon further investigation, the method I recommended is deprecated. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: @swalkner Did you added all url schemas mentioned here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios ?